# C++/OpenCV find objects on an image

Tags: c++, opencv

I have to find a couple of objects on an image. For example find all black pawns on a chessboard:

[image]

How can I achieve that,using OpenCV ?

I think about cv::matchTemplate, however I'm not sure how would it proceed with different pawn backgrounds. I'm also not sure if I can easily get all matchings in that way.

Comment: so, you already found one of the flaws in the matchTemplate approach - it just does not deal with transparency

Comment: do you want a generic solution - like for every state of the board ? And for any kind of board - different styles, pieces and colors? I just wanted to clarify that :)

Comment: Yes, it should be a generic solution. For example - it could be also a checkers (with different image and template of course).

Comment: Well for checkers, you might want to add the color information to that "ID table" thing :)

Comment: Ok just realized that you want black pawns, you need the color anyways, updated the answer

Comment: I think this can be solved using HOG. And for the colour, simply using gray intensity to identify it

Comment: Yep, hog + svm is yet another solution

Comment: a very simple solution would be to create your own "matchTemplate" function which uses a "mask", too (which removes your background). This might be a little slower and some work to create the templates (or better the masks for the templates), but should give very good results for the case that the image objects match the templates perfectly or very good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with corner detection (well known shi tomasi method, or smt like line detection and intersection,  since it should work better for your case) and collection of 64 subsamples of image -the squares. If the board is ideal - pure birds eye view -and you know the size (8x8 here), then just crop it into WxH pieces. You should save these samples with their coordinates (b6, h1 etc).

For every square, a low pass filter smt like gaussian, then otsu threshold and contour detection should give you at most one big contour. If there is none, that square is empty.

You can try to get the contours from the initial state of the board, and name them. This is your training data. Since pieces are not gonna differ much; 1 sample is enough :) Save a "white pawn"s (any square from 2nd row initially) area, hu moments and color (mean rgb value is OK). Then save a "black pawn". Then "white queen" and "black queen" (d4 d8). Do that area, moment, color table for all pieces.

Later, for any state of the board, you can try to match hu moments, color and area of your contour -output of those squares, using your identification table. Of course some statistical method like knn could help you there. You can also utilize matchShapes method.

At last you identify your contour smt like black knight, red checker piece,  etc.